# pass sheet to a function (excel vba)

Tags: vba, excel

I've been trying to pass a sheet in my workbook to a function, but it doesn't seem to be working. The function is

```
Private Sub passToSheet(theData As Variant, Optional mySheet As Worksheet)
```

I have tried doing

```
Dim mySheet as Worksheet
Set mySheet = "Results"
```

then to call the function

```
passToSheet theData mySheet
```

but it doesn't seem to work. I'm not really sure what to google to get the right way to reference the worksheet though! Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use

```
'Set mySheet to worksheet
Set mySheet = Worksheets("Results")
```

to get a reference to the Worksheet.