# Passing worksheet as argument to a sub routine

Tags: vba, excel

I know there are many questions out there on this topic yet I am still struggling with a subscript out of range? Yes the workbook I am importing does have a sheet entitled `LSL Recon`, I verified. I have debugged and substituted `LSL Recon` with `Import Sheets(1)` (as in `Sheet1`) and then the procedure does continue a bit further but does not import anything into the array.

```
Option Explicit

Public FILENAME, c_DATE, cNAME As String
'Public ws As Worksheet

Sub main()
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    CLEAR
    Import Sheets("LSL Recon")
    Display_Import
End Sub()

Sub Import(ws As Worksheet)  
    Workbooks.Open FILENAME
    Set TempBook = ActiveWorkbook
    ws.Activate

    cNAME = "Entity"
    cA = Sheets(1).Rows.Find(What:=UCase(cNAME), LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchDirection:=xlNext).Column
    cNAME = "Sector"
    cB = Sheets(1).Rows.Find(What:=UCase(cNAME), LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchDirection:=xlNext).Column
    cNAME = "Date"
    cC = Sheets(1).Rows.Find(What:=UCase(cNAME), LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchDirection:=xlNext).Column
    cNAME = "Client"
    cD = Sheets(1).Rows.Find(What:=UCase(cNAME), LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchDirection:=xlNext).Column
    ...
End Sub()
```

Helpful Questions:
[VBA: Calling a sub on another worksheet with multiple arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27109127/vba-calling-a-sub-on-another-worksheet-with-multiple-arguments)
[pass sheet to a function (excel vba)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2082810/pass-sheet-to-a-function-excel-vba)
[Passing a Worksheet to a subroutine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2376132/passing-a-worksheet-to-a-subroutine)

Comment: You are trying to refer to a sheet called "LSL Recon" in the active workbook, not in the workbook that you are about to open. If you're trying to refer to a sheet in the workbook you're about to open, you'll have to pass the sheet **name** as a String argument instead.

Comment: Further to what @Rory said, if you pass the name as a string, you'll still have to set the worksheet in the sub ... like `Set ws = TempBook.Sheets(sName)` *assuming sName is the string you pass into the sub, instead of ws As Worksheet*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Get rid of your public scope variables, declare ALL variables, and pass arguments as needed:

```
Option Explicit

Sub main()

    Dim FILENAME$
    Dim c_DATE$
    Dim cNAME$
    Dim wsName$
    wsName = "LSL Recon"
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    CLEAR
    Import (wsName)
    Display_Import
End Sub

Sub Import(wsName$)  
    Dim wb as Workbook
    Dim cNames, itm, found
    ' Use an array of items to search for
    cNames = Split("Entity,Sector,Date,Client",",")

    Set wb = Workbooks.Open(FILENAME)

    Set ws = wb.Sheets(wsName)

    For Each itm in cNames
        found = ws.Rows.Find(What:=UCase(cNAME), LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchDirection:=xlNext).Column
        Debug.Print cName " found in column: " & found
    Next

End Sub
```

If you need to return the results of the `.Find` to the main procedure, then change this to a Function, and return a collection object, and call it like so:

```
Set foundItems = Import(wsName)
Dim itm
For each itm in foundItems
    Debug.Print itm
Next
```

Then the function:

```
Function Import(wsName$)  
    Dim wb as Workbook
    Dim ret as New Collection
    Dim cNames, itm, found
    ' Use an array of items to search for
    cNames = Split("Entity,Sector,Date,Client",",")

    Set wb = Workbooks.Open(FILENAME)

    Set ws = wb.Sheets(wsName)

    For Each itm in cNames
        ret.Add ws.Rows.Find(What:=UCase(cNAME), LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchDirection:=xlNext).Column
        Debug.Print cName " found in column: " & ret(ret.Count)
    Next
    'return the collection to the calling procedure
    Set Import = ret
End Function
```

Comment: when you declare 
Sub Import(wsName)  why do you pass Import Sheets(wsName)? First you should always define the type of your paramters  and variables (Dim cNames, itm, found for example declare non typesafe Variant variable). If you would have defined the parameter as String as you should have done, you would become an run time error when trying to pass a entiere worksheet instead of the worksheet name!

Comment: @cboden I changed the function definition to require string, the passing of a worksheet object was an error that I didn't notice in OP's code (to be fair, there were *many* errors in the source) and I have revised that, too. the other variables are type variant and do not need an explicit `As Variant` declaration, `Dim cNames, itm, found` will suffice.

Comment: it's still bad style not to declare the types of vars (and also the return value type for the function is still missing). These Variant vars cause a lot of overhead in the compiler because there has to be an implicit type conversion each time such a var is accessed. So it's wasting of resources. And in addtion type save vars help to put in the right values as you have seen with the example of the worksheet where you expect a string. If you do not programm typesafe such errors hard to find.

Comment: @cboden You're welcome to make edits to my answer if you think it can be improved

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes when you get subscript out of range it is because the sheet you are referring to is not active.   I've had to go to that sheet and click on it.  Programmatically you may want to activate the sheet.